# Ember.js: What file to edit to append forward slash to every route

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js

I'm creating a basic Ember application and I want a forward slash `/` to be appended to the end of every URL. This is so I can use anchor links without the entire page reloading once.

For example, if I go to `localhost:4200/posts` and have an anchor link to `/posts/#top`, the first time the page will reload because the original URL is `/posts` and not `/posts/`.

Now I already know *how* to append a forward slash to the end of every URL using Javascript, but my question is how to do it with Ember. Is there a file where I can define this rule for every route in my application? Or would I have to define these rules for every single route I want to add a forward slash?

Comment: Maybe this is useful https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/configuring-ember/specifying-url-type/#toc_hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation of URLs is the responsibility of the `Location` API.  By default, you can specify what implementation of the Location API you want to use via the `location` property in the `Router`.  You can create your own Location provider and register it and then specify that one in your `Router`.  This is not something I have ever tried to do, but you may be able to extend one of the existing implementations (e.g. `hash` or `history`).

See the details of implementing the `Location` API here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.7.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/location/api.js

Then, in some initializer, you should be able to do:

```
import CustomLocation from 'my/custom/location/api/implementation.js';
import Router from 'router';

Router.reopen({
    location: 'customLocation',
    customLocation: CustomLocation
});
```